# How to sort RDD of Nested-List Structure by Value in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD with the following (key, value) format:

```
[((u'en', 1),[('term1', 2),('term2', 8),('term3', 6))]
```

As noticed, the `value` here is a list of tuples: `(term,count)`

I tried to sort this rdd by value using:

```
.map(lambda (a,b): (b,a)).sortByKey(False).map(lambda (a,b): (b,a))
```

But it produced a sorted RDD by both `term` and `count`

The question is how to sort this RDD by `count` only to produce the following:

```
[((u'en', 1),[('term2', 8),('term3', 6),('term1', 2))]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your RDD comprises of key, value pairs where the key is a tuple itself, and the value is a list of tuples and you want to only sort that list of tuples:

```py
rdd.map(lambda (k, v): (k, sorted(v, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)))
```

If you want to further sort the result of that by the count in the key tuple (the 2 in `('en', 2)`), you can do:

```py
rdd.map(lambda (k, v): (k, sorted(v, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)))
   .sortBy(lambda (k, v): k[1], False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure that I understand your question, however I think that you want to sort the `List` which is the value of each `RDD` entry, using the second value of each`tuple`.

```py
from operator import itemgetter

rdd = sc.parallelize([("a", [("x", 1), ("y", 2), ("z", 3), ("a", 4), ("b", 5)]), 
                      ("b", [("u", 7), ("d", 6),("p", 5), ("v", 8), ("b", 10)])])
rdd.collect()

# [('a', [('x', 1), ('y', 2), ('z', 3), ('a', 4), ('b', 5)]),
#  ('b', [('u', 7), ('d', 6), ('p', 5), ('v', 8), ('b', 10)])]

rdd = rdd.map(lambda (k, l): (k, sorted(l, key=itemgetter(0), reverse=True)))
rdd.collect()

# [('a', [('b', 5), ('a', 4), ('z', 3), ('y', 2), ('x', 1)]),
#  ('b', [('b', 10), ('v', 8), ('u', 7), ('d', 6), ('p', 5)])]
```

You can find other ways to sort `list`s [Sorting lists in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).